# Place detail request failing - reference too long

Tags: java, google-maps, google-places-api

I have a small java app that, given a list of references for google places, must get back the Id's for each of said google places (long story short, we were storing references for places instead of their Id's, and only now realized that references are not unique per place).

My app works perfectly for about 95% of the places in the list, but fails with a "NOT_FOUND" status code for some records. Some investigation reveals that the place reference for these particular places is (when combined with the https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?sensor=false&key=myApiKey prefix) about 2 characters too long for a URL. The last couple of characters are getting truncated.

My initial thought was that I would just make a POST request to the google places API, but I'm getting back "REQUEST_DENIED" status code from the google servers when sending the same into as a POST request.

Is there anyway around this, or is this just an emergent bug with the google places API (now that the number of places has pushed the reference too long?).

I should also note that the places that fail are all recently added by our application.

This is what my current (working for 95%) code looks like:

```
public static JSONObject getPlaceInfo(String reference) throws Exception
{
URL places = new URL("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?sensor=false&key="+apiKey+"&reference="+reference);
    URLConnection con = places.openConnection();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    StringBuffer input = new StringBuffer();
    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
        input.append(inputLine);
    in.close();

    JSONObject response = (JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON(input.toString());
    return response;
}
```

and this is what my "ACCESS_DENIED" post code looks like:

```
public static JSONObject getPlaceInfo(String reference) throws Exception
{
    String data = URLEncoder.encode("sensor", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("true", "UTF-8");
    data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("key", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(apiKey, "UTF-8");
    data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("reference", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(reference, "UTF-8");

    URL places = new URL("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json");
    URLConnection con = places.openConnection();

    con.setDoOutput(true);
    OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());
    wr.write(data);
    wr.flush();

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    StringBuffer input = new StringBuffer();
    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
        input.append(inputLine);
    in.close();

    JSONObject response = (JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON(input.toString());
    return response;
}
```

An example of the reference that fails is:

```
CnRtAAAAxm0DftH1c5c6-krpWWZTT51uf0rDqCK4jikWV6eGfXlmKxrlsdrhFBOCgWOqChc1Au37inhf8HzjEbRdpMGghYy3dxGt17FEb8ys2CZCLHyC--7Vf1jn-Yn1kfZfzxznTJAbIEg6422q1kRbh0nl1hIQ71tmdOVvhdTfY_LOdbEoahoUnP0SAoOFNkk_KBIvTW30btEwkZs
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You're sending your request parameters in the body, which isn't supported by the API. There's a good answer about GET and request params at:

[HTTP GET with request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body)

The following code should work for Place detail requests:

```
private static final String PLACES_API_BASE = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place";
private static final String TYPE_DETAILS = "/details";
private static final String OUT_JSON = "/json";

HttpURLConnection conn = null;
StringBuilder jsonResults = new StringBuilder();
try {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(PLACES_API_BASE);
    sb.append(TYPE_DETAILS);
    sb.append(OUT_JSON);
    sb.append("?sensor=false");
    sb.append("&key=" + API_KEY);
    sb.append("&reference=" + URLEncoder.encode(reference, "utf8"));

    URL url = new URL(sb.toString());
    conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

    // Load the results into a StringBuilder
    int read;
    char[] buff = new char[1024];
    while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
        jsonResults.append(buff, 0, read);
    }
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    return null;
} catch (IOException e) {
    return null;
} finally {
    if (conn != null) {
        conn.disconnect();
    }
}

try {
    // Create a JSON object hierarchy from the results
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonResults.toString()).getJSONObject("result");
    jsonObj.getString("name");
} catch (JSONException e) {
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error processing JSON results", e);
}
```

Comment: This does solve the ACCESS_DENIED message (and explains why it didnt work, I'd +1 if my rep was high enough! ), but it's more or less the same as my first (95% working) code snippet. This doesn't solve the issue of the GET url being too long because of a huge reference parameter.